# Google play services - current location

Tags: geolocation, google-play-services, android-location

I am using google play services to get current location in my app, every time requesting a new current location instead of last known location.

In a few devices ( example LG-V30 ) I won't get current location within 10 sec( I have added 10 sec expiry time) , other apps like google maps will get a current location.

Why my app not getting new current location updates and google maps getting updates ? Why is this strange behaviour observed?

Comment: please show a bit of code so that we can have an idea about what you are missing

Answer (score 0):

Using the Google Play Services location APIs, your app can request the last known location of the user's device. User's current location are **usually equivalent** to the last known location of the device.

Based from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current):

> When your app is connected to these you can use the fused location
>   provider's `getLastLocation()` method to retrieve the device location.
>   The precision of the location returned by this call is determined by
>   the permission setting you put in your app manifest, as described in
>   the [Specify App Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#permissions) section of this document.
>
> **Note:** On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, if an app is running in the background when it requests the current location, then
>   the device calculates the location only a few times each hour. To
>   learn how to adapt your app to these calculation limits, see
>   [Background Location
>   Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits).